# Vue.js, Vuex, Vue-Router SPA and scaling the app client side vs server side

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex, server-side-rendering

1. I'm rewriting a very, very, large and complex application
2. I'm using Vue/Vuex/Vue Router
3. It's a single page application with a persistent desktop-like UI.
4. It has over 150 'forms' that correspond to about that many objects.
5. Periodically we have to add new forms.
6. Let's pretend that I will show each of these forms in a modal (I won't, but it's easy to envision)
7. The app is already about 15mb.

Regarding those forms, what should I consider when choosing between rendering them on the server and loading them into the modal, versus including the component in the application and maintaining separation of responsibility between the client and server?

I mean, either we pay the cost of re-downloading every now and then, or we pay the cost of separating responsibilities between client and server, and the attendant server load.  I desperately want to keep the app and backend separate, because at present the backend is just an api. But I'm worried that the size of the app will increase such that we resist issuing new forms (functionality).

Unfortunately, without experience creating something of this scale in Vue, I can't predict (even though I've tried) whether I'm talking about regular 20mb updates, or 200mb updates...

Thoughts appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three choices:

- 1 - render them on the server, say in Laravel/blade or some equivalent, and just present them in the vue app.
- 2 - render them on the server in vue.
- 3 - incorporate them into the app.

The decision criteria is:

- 1 - encapsulation: preserve separation of app and api or break it.
- 2 - experience: preserve the experience of the spa at the cost of more frequent downloads as new features (api services) are offered. Or the opposite.

We chose to increase the frequency of downloads despite the size increase in order to preserve the separation of UI and API as well as the user experience. Furthermore it maintained our relatively simple build and deploy processes.